# Housekeeping in git repository

Tags: git

I have a very big subversion repository (> 200,000 commits) that we recently migrated to git.

Over the years a lot of people made tiny mistakes like adding iso or msi packages, Adding folders that were not supposed to be added, etc... We cleaned that by removing the files/folders and committed. The repository grew, but that wasn't an issue as SVN did good sparse checkout.

Now on git a client needs to pull the whole history and the local clone is about 50GB now. Time for some housekeeping…

Is there a way to remove all files from history, that have been deleted at some in the past?
Or create a new repo and move all those files over, that are existing in the lastest commit?

I have worked with the `git filter-branch` command, which helped. But only for those files, that I know the path for. 
I also used `git log --diff-filter=D --summary` to get a list of all deletes, but there are thousands…

OK, in the end, I can simply start a new repository and copy the latest files in it. I will lose the history then, but can keep the original big repo as an archive repo to lookup history when required.

I really hope there are better approaches...

Comment: That's a tough problem since, well, those files *are* part of the history. Any method for excluding these files must therefore rewrite history. That said, maybe you'll want to take a look at the shallow clone feature of `git`: It allows you to exclude any number of commits from the `git clone` command. This effectively prunes the commit DAG at the places that you specify. I guess it should be possible to have one `git` repo with the full history, and a shallow clone of that which excludes your past sins, where the later is used for new development while the former is used for archeology, only.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is too difficult to achieve this after migration to git. But I can achieve it before.

I did this:

```
svnadmin dump …
```

to create a dump file.

```
svndumpfilter exclude …
```

to exclude all stuff I no longer need.
To get a complete list of the repository including deleted items, I did this:

```
svndumpfilter exclude "*" …
```

The cool thing is, that svndumpfilter lists out all files it excluded in a structured sorted output. Since I excluded everything, I got a complete directory.

I ran svndumpfilter a couple of times to remove all unwanted stuff. Then reimported the subversion repository as a new repository and then used this to migrate to git.